# No module named site OSGEO4W

Tags: python

I have a problem when I create a batch file to run in windows cmd. The error is the same: No module named site. I set the PYTHONPATH to ...\python27\Lib and the PYTHONHOME to ...\python27. I confirm that and the error continue.

The batch file is like this:

```
@ECHO ON
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
SET PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib
PATH %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts;%PATH%
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts\sentinelsat.exe -u <user> -p <passowrd> -s 20150101 -e 20150105 --instrument MSI --uuid 0d7bb0a5-5a0e-4de4-a41e-1599edf26825 --path <path> -d
@pause
```

What is the solution?

Comment: What is the code you are asking about?

Comment: I create a batch file to run a command line from sentinelsat library. I edit the question with the batch file.

Comment: And the Python code involved is...?

Comment: I call the batch file in a script writted in Python. However I am trying to run the batch code in OSGeo4W environment and it gave me the error: No module named site.

Comment: And the Python code involved is... ?

Comment: My problem is not in the Python code but in the connection of the Python folder to run the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved.
I added this to my batch:

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"
```